# CSS Transition not working on nested items

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

My transition does not apply to the submenu `<a>` tag. The color change is doing well, but the transition does not trigger on hover. If I apply the same rules, on another element with a main class, it works well. The problem is with nested elements or CSS subclasses/selectors. Any ideas?

I have the following HTML, JS structure & CSS:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 $('.menu_container').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('ul', this).show();
});
 $('.menu_container').mouseout(function(e) {
    $('ul', this).hide();
});
});
```

```css
.menu               { background:#f8f8f8; color:#707070; text-align:center; }
.menu li            { margin-bottom:0 }
.menu li            { display:inline-block; font-size:16px; border-top:2px solid #f8f8f8;  }
.menu li:hover      { background-color:#022a3b; background-color:#022a3b;   border-top:2px solid #06a7ea; text-decoration:none;}
.menu li a          { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131;  }
.menu li a:hover    { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li span       { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131; cursor:pointer; }
.menu li span:hover { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li.menu_container         { position:relative; display:inline-table; }
.menu li.menu_container ul      { display:none; position:absolute; top:51px; left:0; background:#022a3b; padding-left:0; padding:5px; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li   { display:table; max-width:200px; min-width:130px; text-align:left; border-top:none; margin-left:10px; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a     { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; padding:10px; transition:color 2s; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a:hover   { color:#FF0000; }
```

```html
<nav class="container-fluid menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu_container">
            <span>Home
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Live example: http://thyalie.ro/casedevanzareoradea/

Comment: The only transition I can see (apart from the `color` one) is `transition:margin-left 2s;`, and it does not get altered by any other style declaration, so it makes sense that no other transitions happen.

Comment: Oh, i forgot do delete the transition from .menu li.menu_container ul li. Anyway, I tried both of your suggetion, but with no success.

I found something: If i put display:block on the submenu, the transition is working! But it's not a solution. My menu should be hidden, and with Jquery show() hide() i change the display

Comment: Could you just tell us what transition you are talking about then? I can't see the problem.

Comment: The transition with the color: .menu li.menu_container ul li a     { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; padding:10px; transition:color 2s; }

Comment: Thats quite odd. I can't even isolate the issue properly. I'm upvoting the question and hoping somebody else can point out what I'm overlooking. To be honest though, it seems as if _none_ of your values for that nested `a` seem to be applied...

Comment: I cant get it working here in code snippet editor, but you can find the live example here: http://thyalie.ro/casedevanzareoradea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events rather than `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

`mouseover` and `mouseout` fire every time you hover from one element to another within `.menu_container`. Therefore, when you hover from one element to a submenu item, the submenu `ul`'s inline style is being rapidly changed from `display: none` to `display: block`.  This causes the transition on the links to not take effect.

[This jQuery page](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) has a good example of the differences between the events.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 $('.menu_container').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $('ul', this).show();
});
 $('.menu_container').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $('ul', this).hide();
});
});
```

```css
.menu               { background:#f8f8f8; color:#707070; text-align:center; }
.menu li            { margin-bottom:0 }
.menu li            { display:inline-block; font-size:16px; border-top:2px solid #f8f8f8;  }
.menu li:hover      { background-color:#022a3b; background-color:#022a3b;   border-top:2px solid #06a7ea; text-decoration:none;}
.menu li a          { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131;  }
.menu li a:hover    { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li span       { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131; cursor:pointer; }
.menu li span:hover { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li.menu_container         { position:relative; display:inline-table; }
.menu li.menu_container ul      { display:none; position:absolute; top:47px; left:0; background:#022a3b; padding-left:0; padding:5px; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li   { display:table; max-width:200px; min-width:130px; text-align:left; border-top:none; margin-left:10px; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a     { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; padding:10px; transition:color 2s; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a:hover   { color:#FF0000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="container-fluid menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu_container">
            <span>Home
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I agree, there are better ways of implementing a dropdown navigation menu.  But I'm answering OP's question of why his transition isn't working.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you, now it's working! Somethinghere's answer is much more elegant, but your definitely answered the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript seems to be interfering with displaying your menu correctly. You do not need any javascript to make this work, however, you can do it on pure CSS, by adding this line:

```
.menu li.menu_container:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Because a hover hovers over the parent as well, this works just fine an requires no JS whatsoever.

```css
.menu               { background:#f8f8f8; color:#707070; text-align:center; }
.menu li            { margin-bottom:0 }
.menu li            { display:inline-block; font-size:16px; border-top:2px solid #f8f8f8;  }
.menu li:hover      { background-color:#022a3b; background-color:#022a3b;   border-top:2px solid #06a7ea; text-decoration:none;}
.menu li a          { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131;  }
.menu li a:hover    { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li span       { padding:13px 13px 16px 13px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#313131; cursor:pointer; }
.menu li span:hover { color:#06a7ea; }
.menu li.menu_container         { position:relative; display:inline-table; }
.menu li.menu_container ul      { display:none; position:absolute; top:47px; left:0; background:#022a3b; padding-left:0; padding:5px; }
.menu li.menu_container:hover ul { display: block; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li   { display:table; max-width:200px; min-width:130px; text-align:left; border-top:none; margin-left:10px; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a     { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; padding:10px; transition:color 2s; }
.menu li.menu_container ul li a:hover   { color:#FF0000; }
```

```html
<nav class="container-fluid menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu_container">
            <span>Home
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is the most elegant answer, thank you somethinghere! :)

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
transition: color 2s;
```

to

```
.menu li.menu_container ul li a:hover
```

Comment: My bad @somethinghere - bit rude but whatever. Needed to refresh my console as messed with the js. So here goes the above as you mentioned is incorrect the error comes from the ` $('.mobil-menu-button').click(function(e) {
        $('.menu_ul').toggle();
    });` in the js file as its fighting against the other 2 calls for `hide` and `show`. Hope this clarifies. Ta.

Comment: Remove or refactor the toggle this will resolve the immediate issue.

Comment: Sorry but it is not just that the answer does not work, it's that is is also posted with as minimal amount of explanation as possible. Post what you commented above here as a full fledged post with a little bit of explanation as to whats going on and how to fix it, and I will relent and upvote it again (and, you know, swallow my pride). I only meant that no explanation solutions with a `do this` are really not helping anyone learn and figure things out. It fixes things, but is - in the end - not helping.